# Open overlay component when button is pressed

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-elements

I am using the [react-native-element Overlay](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/overlay/) component. What I am trying to do is to define a button on header of toolbar, when clicking on the button opens the overlay from the bottom of the toolbar. I tried:

My custom component which wraps the Overlay component:

```
import {Overlay} from 'react-native-elements';
...
const MyOverlay = ({isVisible}) => {
   return (
    <View>
      <Overlay isVisible={visible} onBackdropPress={true}>
        <Text>Hello from Overlay!</Text>
      </Overlay>
    </View>
  );
}
```

In one of my screens, I show a button on the header bar (toolbar), in the `onPress` callback of the button I try to open `MyOverlay`:

```
const MyScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
   ...
   navigation.setOptions({
      headerTitle: props => (
        <Button
          title="open"
          color="#f194ff"
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          onPress={() => <MyOverlay isVisible={true} />}
        />
      ),
    });
   ...

}
```

When I run the app, the button is shown on the toolbar, but when clicking on it, there is nothing happening.

My questions:

1. how to open `MyOverlay` when that button pressed?
2. How to make sure the overlay view opens from the bottom of the toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

**define state**

```
const MyScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {

const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const toggleOverlay = () => {
    setVisible(!visible);
  };

....
```

**add overylay in main return function**

```
return (
.....
<MyOverlay isVisible={visible} />
)
```

**set state when button press**

```
<Button
          title="open"
          color="#f194ff"
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          onPress={() => toggleOverlay()}
        />
```

Comment: Why return the overlay in the main return function? The main return function is supposed to return MyScreen layout. If I return the overlay component in the main return function how am I supposed to show the main layout of MyScreen then?

Comment: return main layout with and include `MyOverlay` component . it will show when press button.